# Using Iterable and numeric as input in a function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, mean, iterable

I've written a mean function in python

```
    def mean(*args):
        numbers = args
        sm=0
        length = len(numbers)
        if length>0:
            for num in numbers:
                sm = sm+num
            return sm/length  
        else:
            return 'FAIL'
```

which is working fine with numeric values. Now I want to modify it so that it also accepts iterables in the input.

Modified function:

```
    def mean_new(*args):
        numbers = args
        sm=0
        count=0
        for num in numbers:
            if iter(num):
                data = list(num)
                sm += sum(data)
                count+=len(data)
            else:
                sm = sm+num
                count+=1
    return sm/count
```

mean_new function is not working and giving me an error 'int' object is not iterable. Could you please help me identify what I'm doing wrong in the mean_new function. 
mean_new function should work with both numeric and iterable input.

Comment: What is `iter(num)` here doing? Exactly *what* do you want to realize by accepting iterables? Can you provide some sample input?

Comment: thats not how you check if something is iterable ... `if isinstance(obj,collection.iterable)` or something like that

Comment: as an aside, `return 'FAIL'` is a bad design decision. Throw an error, don't return a magic string.

Comment: It should work with the following inputs:
mean_new(1,2,3,4)
mean_new([1,1,1,2])
mean_new(1, (2,), 3, [4,6]))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if an object is iterable, you can indeed use `iter(object)`, but not as a condition in an `if` statement, but in a `try` block, since `iter()` would raise a `TypeError` exception if the object is not iterable. But then, since you are throwing away the iterator returned by `iter()` and are instead using the `list()` constructor to convert the iterable into a list, you can simply put the `try` block around `list()` instead:

```
for num in numbers:
    try:
        data = list(num)
        sm += sum(data)
        count += len(data)
    except TypeError:
        sm = sm + num
        count += 1
```